# C multiple pipes

Tags: c, pipe

I am trying to implement multiple pipes in C like

```
ls - al | less | wc
```

I have trouble with creating the pipeline. I have a loop that is supposed to create the processes and connect them with pipes:

```
for(i=0;i<num_cmds;i++){ 
     create_commands(cmds[i]);
}
```

My `create_commands()` function looks like this

```
void create_commands (char cmd[MAX_CMD_LENGTH]) // Command be processed
{
    int pipeid[2];
    pipe(pipeid);

    if (childpid = fork()) 
    {
        /* this is the parent process */
        dup2(pipeid[1], 1); // dup2() the write end of the pipe to standard output.
        close(pipeid[1]); // close() the write end of the pipe  

        //parse the command
        parse_command(cmd, argvector);

        // execute the command
        execvp(argvector[0], argvector);

        close(1); // close standard output
    }
    else
    {
        /* child process */
        dup2( pipeid[0], 0); // the read end of the pipe to standard input
        close( pipeid[0] ); // close() the read end of the pipe 
    }

}
```

But this doesn't work, I'm getting my stdin and stdout messed up.
Could anyone please point me to what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popen() function executes the command specified by the string command. It creates a pipe between the calling program and the executed command, and returns a pointer to a stream that can be used to either read from or write to the pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *fp;
    int status;
    int PATH_MAX = 1024;
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    fp = popen("ls -al | less | wc", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        /* Handle error */;


     while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
         printf("%s", path);


     status = pclose(fp);
     if (status == -1) {
    /* Error reported by pclose() */
     } else {
    /* Use macros described under wait() to inspect `status' in order
       to determine success/failure of command executed by popen() */
     }

}
```

You can use a preset string to be called within popen(), you can also use your argv[] arguments to be piped in you'ld like.

popen() gives you a pipe, a FIFO First In First Out stream, and popen also feeds the STDOUT back to your program.

Here's the man page for popen(): 
http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

Comment: Thank you for pointing out popen(), unfortunately I am required to use the pipe() and fork() system calls.

Comment: One way of doing this is by using a combination:
1) Use pipe to create the pipe 
2) Use fork to create the subprocess, in your case: less/vim
3) Use dup2 to force the subprocess to use the pipe as its standard input or output channel,
4) Use exec to execute the new program.